# RemoveEventListener when user resizes window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I followed a tutorial to create a slider effect. The problem is that the effect doesn't look great on smaller screens. I can deal with the styles quite easily with media queries, the problem is that this isn't the case with the javascript. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="skewed">
  <div class="layer bottom">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content-body content-body-bottom">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
      </div>

      <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="layer top">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content-body content-body-top">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="handle"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
    overflow: hidden;

    .content-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
    }

    .content-body {
        width: 25%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .bg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        background-color: #191919;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

.bottom {
    z-index: 1;

    .content-body {
        right: 5%;
    }
}

.top {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50vw;

    .content-body {
        left: 5%;
        color: #fff;
    }
}

.test {
    height: 70%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    right: 5%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 10%;

    &.top-image {
        right: 5%;
    }

    &.bottom-image {
        left: 5%;
    }
}

.handle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 0px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.skewed {
    .handle {
        top: 50%;
        transform: rotate(30deg) translateY(-50%);
        transform-origin: top;
        height: 200%;
    }

    .top {
        transform: skew(-30deg);
        margin-left: -1000px;
        width: calc(50vw + 1000px);

        .content-wrap {
            transform: skew(30deg);
            margin-left: 1000px;
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #about-heading {
        padding: 70px 20px 0;
        white-space: normal;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }

    #wrapper {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .layer {
        position: static;
    }

    .handle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
window.onresize = e => {
    const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
    const topLayer = wrapper.querySelector('.top')
    const handle = wrapper.querySelector('.handle')
    let skew = 0
    let delta = 0

    const handleMouseMove = e => {
        delta = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5
        handle.style.left = e.clientX + delta + 'px'
        topLayer.style.width = e.clientX + skew + delta + 'px'
    }

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 800) {

        if (wrapper.className.indexOf('skewed') != -1) {
            skew = 1000
        }

        wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    } else {
        wrapper.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the viewport is greater than 800px, the slider effect is working. However, when I resize the window to less than 800px, the slider is still there. My guess is that for some reason I'm not removing the event hooked to the wrapper element properly. I've got a codepen of the code [here](https://codepen.io/edward-hong/pen/WMYjYq). Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you defined `handleMouseMove` inside `onresize`, so it creates a different variable every time it calls `onresize` and you remove the new created one not the one previously assigned.

The solution is to define the `handleMouseMove` function out of the resize. by doing that you will add and remove the same event.

Your code should be like this:

```
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
  const topLayer = wrapper.querySelector('.top')
  const handle = wrapper.querySelector('.handle')
  let skew = 0
  let delta = 0
  const handleMouseMove = e => {
        delta = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5
        handle.style.left = e.clientX + delta + 'px'
        topLayer.style.width = e.clientX + skew + delta + 'px'
    }
  window.onresize = e => {

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 800) {
        console.log('true')

        if (wrapper.className.indexOf('skewed') != -1) {
            skew = 1000
        }

        wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    } else {
        console.log('false')
        wrapper.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    }
}
```